# Show download link after getting email address. PHP/AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, download

we are offering our users software downloads.

we want to be able to show our users the download link after after they submit their email address which will be using ajax (May be?) and their email address will directly go to  icontact.

thanks

Comment: Do you need to validate the email address?

Comment: what is the question? what did you try until now?

Comment: nothing tried so far... sorry for not being so clear... i will try to explain it better next time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a framework? or following model-view-controller pattern?

I thinks a solution (not the best one) is to make the ajax call to save the email, check it was saved correctly and show the link, something like:

```
function saveMail(email){
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  //here you check and show the download link
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      document.getElementById("downloadLink").innerHTML="<a href='download.php'>Download!</a>";   
  }
  var url = "saveEmail.php";
  var params = "email="+email;
  http.open("POST", url, true);
  http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
  http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
  xmlhttp.send(params);
}
```

That should do the trick, but it's by far a very bad code. If you're using MVC you better do this in a controller.

Cheers!

Comment: ok... i get it... so we should be posting to saveEmail.php and then running the curl code in that file... right? i think i got it... is there a way someone can point me to the what will be the curl code.

Comment: you don't need curl for something like this (or probably i didn't understand your problem) just a little Javascript and Ajax technique. BTW are you using a framework? I recommend you to search a little about MVC design patter.